# COM+ exception "Class Not Registered" after Microsoft update in February 2020

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, com+

I have an application which is in Delphi and interacts with other .NET application through old COM+ component. The component is invoked from Delphi code and there was no issue until Microsoft introduced some security patches on Feb 11, 2020 (this year).

The issue it throws now is "Class not registered" After searching a lot on Google, I have tried the following things :

1. As this COM+ component is written in .NET (ComVisible attribute, had an assumption that it needs to be registered again. So tried to register it usign RegAsm using :

   Regasm

But it didn't work though

1. Confirmed if assembly is in GAC. it is placed there indeed.
2. List item
3. Deleting registration of the DLL and then registering using regasm /u but that also provided no luck.
4. Some blogs over google suggested about COM+ security. Tried playing with that to.
5. Disabled the COM+ component to test whether COM+ component has any impact and yes indeed it turned to different error. Something like COmponent doesn't exist.
6. Someone suggested to run DCOMCNFG and traverse into DCOM config tree and press "Yes" if there are warnings to record the anomalies in registry. Still no luck.
7. Opened up Registry using RegEdit and tried to permit full control on relevant registries including Microsoft Ole. Still didn't work
8. Also, there were some thoughts around COM security, it was also checked and was permitted well.
   The caveat is if we revert the microsoft patches, it works well again. I matched all the security settings before and after the patches which seems same.

PLEASE suggest if someone has sound knowledge about it.

[image: Error it is showing]

Adding more details:

[COM+ Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhZ8o.png)

[COM component properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8o2K.png)

Here is the .NET COM component code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.EnterpriseServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml.XPath;

using Acclipse.Config;
using Acclipse.FileSystem.Shared;
using Aspose.Words;

[assembly: ApplicationActivation(ActivationOption.Library)]
[assembly: ApplicationAccessControl(false)]
[assembly: ApplicationName("Acclipse FileSystem Client")]
[assembly: Description("Client to communicate with the Acclipse FileSystem server.")]

namespace Acclipse.FileSystem
{
    class Singleton
    {
        private static Singleton m_Instance = new Singleton();

        private Singleton()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Singleton.Create");
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        }

        private IRemotedFS m_IRemotedFS;

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Instance;
            }
        }

        internal static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve", "Acclipse.FileSystem");
            try
            {
                string[] parts = args.Name.Split(',');
                string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), string.Format("{0}.dll", parts[0]));
                //Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Loading resolved assembly at {0}", path), "Acclipse.Licencing");

                Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Assembly is {0}, looking for {1}", a.FullName, args.Name), "Acclipse.FileSystem");
                if (a.FullName != args.Name)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Unable to load correct assembly");
                }

                return a;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to resolve with error {0}", ex.Message), "Acclipse.FileSystem");
            }

            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        }

        public IRemotedFS FS
        {
            get
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Get IRemotedFS", "Acclipse.FileSystem");
                if (m_IRemotedFS == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("Creating IRemotedFS", "Acclipse.FileSystem");

                        Trace.WriteLine("Configfile at " + Path.GetFullPath("Config.file"), "Acclipse.FileSystem");
                        ConfigFile config = ConfigFile.FromFile("Config.file");

                        Trace.WriteLine("Loading url", "Acclipse.FileSystem");
                        string url = config["FileStore.Url"];


                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                        {
                            throw new ApplicationException("Url of server is not configured in Config.file");
                        }

                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Url is {0}", url));

                        TcpClientChannel chan = new TcpClientChannel();
                        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);
                        m_IRemotedFS = Activator.GetObject(typeof(IRemotedFS), url) as IRemotedFS;

                        if (m_IRemotedFS == null)
                        {
                            Trace.WriteLine("Oops, RemoteFS is null!!");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Error in getting FS *** {0} - {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                Trace.WriteLine("..Done");
                return m_IRemotedFS;
            }

            internal set
            {
                m_IRemotedFS = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("Acclipse.FileSystem.SqlZipClient.SqlZipFileSystemRemote")]
    [Guid("5A940543-24EF-4f31-B45B-6832C8211986")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [JustInTimeActivation(true)]
    public class SqlZipFileSystemRemote : ServicedComponent, IFileSystem
    {
        private IConfigFile m_Config;

        public SqlZipFileSystemRemote()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("SqlZipFileSystemRemote Created", "Acclipse.FileSystem");
            m_Config = DefaultConfigFile.FromFile("Config.file");
        }

        static SqlZipFileSystemRemote()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Set Aspose.Words license info", "Acclipse.FileSystem");
            try
            {
                new License().SetLicense("Acclipse.FileSystem.SqlZipClient.Aspose.Words.lic");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception encountered setting license details: {0}", ex.StackTrace), "Acclipse.FileSystem");
                throw;
            }

            Trace.WriteLine("Done", "Acclipse.FileSystem");
        }

        internal void AttachConfigFile(IConfigFile config)
        {
            this.m_Config = config;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think is putting out the message "Could not create document... Document creation has been cancelled... Class not registered"?

Comment: This "could not create document" is our own custom message when there is an exception. The internal error is "Class not registered". It happens on a point where the code try to access that COM+ component

Comment: Can you try revert the update, confirm that it's working, then install this [specific](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2020-0685) update, and confirm it's no longer working?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the question Martheen. It works perfectly if we revert the MS update

Comment: Which of the Feb 2020 patches introduces the problem/what is its MS KB number and have you asked MS about it?  Also ISTM this q should have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes Martyn. As we are premium client of MS, so did ask but they are even struggling since 3 months. Provided them logs over logs but still the issue is not sorted. Will try to create small example but I am not Delphi expert so just tryign to create a bare minimum form.

Comment: Well, maybe MS can't reproduce it because they aren't trying to invoke it from a Delphi app.  Of course there is only any point in asking for help here if readers can reproduce the problem, so I think you should include in your mre a minimal freeware server as well as a Delphi client.  Btw does the problem persist with the Win update that installs the new Edge?

Comment: You could try loading your COM object from a simple .vbs script (see [here](https://gist.github.com/simply-coded/758e2557ccd1a55b46765d8bb1099ec6) for an example).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  Can't say I disagree with your dupe hammer, but I think a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including minimal server + Delphi client would be a useful q.

Comment: @MartynA: Yes, this Q is identical to the old one. If this Q is on-topic, *the old one* should be reopened; if not, but if it still can be made on-topic by means of some editing, *the old one* should be edited and then possibly reopened. I'm not quite sure I understood the implied suggestion in your comment, though. Do you think this Q should have been closed as off-topic instead of being marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  I think it's both off-topic for lacking an mre and a clear duplicate.  I understand the OP's frustration, but think he would do better to start over with the kind of server + client I suggested than try to salvage the original q.

Comment: Fair enough. @VikasKumar: Listen to MartynA. He knows what he is talking about!

Comment: As does @AndreasRejbrand, of course.

Comment: @VikasKumar: can you specify the exact MS KB that is causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks @Martyn. I will get back to you after making a VBS file to access the COM component

Comment: Well, ood luck, but in your position I'd be wondering whether I actually need all the COM+ and Net baggage.  'Simplify, simplify' as they say ...

Comment: Hi All,
I figured out the real issue but why is that don't know. The issue is in OLE object used open Word document in Delphi. I tried to open Word in Memory and after that I access this COM component it blows up. If I comment out the usage of OLE for word and simply access this COM, it works. GetActiveOLEObject